# I am getting An Error with c# and Docusign How Do i resolve this error

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am getting the error
Unable to load template. Unable to load template from TemplateReference(0). Error: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

below is a simplified version of the code i am using...
If i don't use the template reference type of the code everything works fine.  But when i start using a template reference.. Nothing works and i get this error.  Anyone have a suggestion?

```
      TemplateReference _tempRef = new TemplateReference();
      TemplateReference[] _tempRefs = new TemplateReference[] { };
      TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment[] _roleAssignmentArray = new TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment[] { };
      Recipient[] _recipientsArray = new Recipient[] { };



      EnvelopeInformation envelope = new EnvelopeInformation();

        Recipient recipient = new Recipient();
        recipient.ID = "1";
        recipient.Email = "someemail@somewhere.com";
        recipient.UserName = "Some Person";
        recipient.Type = RecipientTypeCode.Signer;
        recipient.RequireIDLookup = false;
        Array.Resize(ref _roleAssignmentArray, 1);
        Array.Resize(ref _recipientsArray, 1);


        _recipientsArray[0] = recipient;

        var saRoleAssignment = new TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment
        {
            RecipientID = "1",
            RoleName = "SA"
        };
        _roleAssignmentArray[0] = saRoleAssignment;
        var reference = new Docusign.TemplateReference();
        reference.Template = "49C0BE2B-48F7-4F38-B44A-19EB8E6A1A38";
        reference.Document = new Docusign.Document();
        reference.Document.PDFBytes = new byte[0];
        reference.Document.ID = Convert.ToString(1);
        reference.Document.Name = "please work";

        reference.RoleAssignments = _roleAssignmentArray;
        Array.Resize(ref _tempRefs, 1);
        _tempRefs[1 - 1] = reference;

        //.NET

        //.NET
        envelope.AccountId = "accountID";
        envelope.Subject = "Sample Application";
        envelope.EmailBlurb = "You can add a personal message here.";


        APIServiceSoapClient apiService = new APIServiceSoapClient();
        apiService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "userhere";
        apiService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
        var status = apiService.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(_tempRefs, _recipientsArray, envelope, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using DocuSign's SOAP api instead of REST then you should definitely familiarize yourself with the SOAP SDK on GitHub:

https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK

There's an MS.NET (C#) version which has sample code that works out of the box, you only need to enter your api credentials.  I suggest you use that as your project base, especially since it was updated recently.

Since you have not identified which line the error is stemming from it's a little hard to debug, but if you look at `SendTemplate.aspx.cs` in the SDK you'll see that the template reference is instantiated like this:

```
// Construct the template reference
var templateReference = new DocuSignAPI.TemplateReference
{
    TemplateLocation = DocuSignAPI.TemplateLocationCode.Server,
    Template = TemplateTable.Value,
    RoleAssignments = CreateFinalRoleAssignments(recipients)
};
```

where `CreateFinalRoleAssignments()` is defined as:

```
protected DocuSignAPI.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment[] CreateFinalRoleAssignments(DocuSignAPI.Recipient[] recipients)
    {
        // Match up all the recipients to the roles on the template
        return recipients.Select(recipient => new DocuSignAPI.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment
            {
                RecipientID = recipient.ID, RoleName = recipient.RoleName
            }).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the line i was missing was TemplateLocation = DocuSignAPI.TemplateLocationCode.Server,